# Could not run ADB

Tags: android-ndk, gdb, adb

I'm having a problem running ndk-gdb.

Here's what I did:

```
~/< my ndk path >/ndk-gdb --adb="< my sdk path >/platform-tools/adb"
```

but it will produce an error :

> Could not run ADB with: ~/< my sdk path >/platform-tools/adb

Any ideas?  I can use ndk-build with no problems.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you execute adb from command line? Have you tried putting absolute path for --adb argument?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. How can I execute adb? 
sorry, but im new to this

Comment: Open terminal or command line, and write there exactly what you wrote in quotes for --adb parameter.

Comment: Hey sorry for late response, I already solved this, the problem was I used "~" for the adb path (idk what's that symbol called). Anyway, thanks for responding.

Comment: It is fine to use ~ symbol for path. ~ symbol means path to your home directory. If you sdk folder is in your home directory, then you can specify it by using ~/sdk

Answer (score 0):

In the adb folder type `adb-killserver`.
Another option is to go to DDMS devices and select `Reset adb`.